# Angular with Mathquill

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, calculator

I am using the library [Mathquill](http://mathquill.com) to render math for a project. I'm also trying to learn Angular, as I think it will improve the structure and maintainability. However, I've come to a problem- Mathquill is designed with the "jQuery programming style" in mind, whereas Angular is, well, not designed with the "jQuery programming style."

For example, the code for an editable Mathquill textbox is `<span class="mathquill-editable"></span>`. To get the latex source from the rendered view, the function `$("#id").mathquill('latex')` is used. However, this doesn't really work well with AngularJS:

```
<span id="input" class="mathquill-editable" ng-model="input">
</span>
<div id="output">
  {{calculate(input);}}
</div>
```

The function `calculate` does calculations based on the **latex** source, but obviously this doesn't work, since `span#input` gets filled by MathQuill with `span`s/`div`s for the rendering of the math. How can I get around this?

Comment: There's no getting 'around' this.  You'll need to go through it.  I'd suggest reading about directives, at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.